# The method 'allocate' isn't defined for the class 'Tensor'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have a problem in an existing app. The problem is it using deprecated version 1 of Flutter. I have fixed other problems but encounter a problem with this code:

```
void copyFrom(Int8List bytes) {
  var size = bytes.length;
  final ptr = allocate<Int8>(count: size);
  final externalTypedData = ptr.asTypedList(size);

  externalTypedData.setRange(0, bytes.length, bytes);
  checkState(TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer(_tensor, ptr.cast(), bytes.length) ==
      TfLiteStatus.ok);
  free(ptr);
}
```

The error show:

```
lib/pages/TFLite/tflite/src/tensor.dart:73:17: Error: The method 'allocate' isn't defined for the class 'Tensor'
'Tensor' is from 'package:aphasia_app/pages/TFLite/tflite/src/tensor.dart' ('lib/pages/TFLite/tflite/src/tensor.dart')
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allocate'.
final ptr = allocate<Int8>(count: size);
            ^^^^^^^^

lib/pages/TFLite/tflite/src/tensor.dart:80:5: Error: The method 'free' isn't defined for the class 'Tensor'.

'Tensor' is from 'package:aphasia_app/pages/TFLite/tflite/src/tensor.dart' ('lib/pages/TFLite/tflite/src/tensor.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'free'.
free(ptr);
^^^^
```

I am not quite sure whether I am using wrong method.

I am using flutter beta channel and here is my Flutter doctor output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 3.3.0-0.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826], locale en-MY)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
• No issues found!
```